# ASP.NET Get data for Details error

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Teste.Models.Suppliers]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Teste.Models.Suppliers'.

my controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var results = from c in db.Suppliers
                  where (c.ID == id)
                  select c;

    /*Suppliers suppliers = db.Suppliers.Find(id);*/
    if (results == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(results);
}
```

View

```
 @model  Teste.Models.Suppliers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Suppliers</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID_Guard)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID_Guard)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Supplier)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Supplier)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Enter)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Enter)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Exit)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Exit)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

How i can solve this?

Solved

I made a new project and worked well ;) thx all

Comment: You may want to start here https://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Childish, but: "teste" < ha!

Comment: I dont see where is the Childish here?  Geoff James

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the actual `Supplier`. You are returning your linq query

So change

```
 if (results == null)
 {
     return HttpNotFound();
 }
 return View(results);
```

To

```
 Supplier supplier = results.FirstOrDefault();
 if (supplier == null)
 {
     return HttpNotFound();
 }
 return View(supplier);
```

Calling `FirstOrDefault()` will run your query and return either the first match or null.

Comment: now gives me other error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Teste.Suppliers', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Teste.Models.Suppliers'.

Comment: Looking at your html you have a viewmodel `Teste.Models.Suppliers` - you need to convert your db.Supplier to your viewmodel supplier by mapping it (most likely) - that one is for you to investigate further.

Comment: @Rgodinho: Looks like you have two models in two namespaces : one under Teste.Models and one directly under Teste. Check the reference of which supplier you are returning from controller action

Comment: Either that or change your ` @model  Teste.Models.Suppliers` to the same namespace as your `Supplier` - as for how - if you wrote everything you're posting then you should know the answer to that...

Comment: maybe its bc my viewmodel its in the same Folder as Models